# Ordinary Differential Equation ( dependant variables)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Say I have two population species snake and chicken. I am conducting one investigation on controlling the number of chicken based on predator species, snake.

The population dynamic of the two species is governed by the following ODE:
$$
\left\{\begin{array}{rcl}
    \dfrac{dC}{dt} &=& bC - aCS \\[0.3cm]
    \dfrac{dS}{dt} &=& eCS - \rho S
\end{array}\right.
$$

where $C(t)$ and $S(t)$ are the number of chicken and snake at time $t$, $\dfrac{dC}{dt}$ and $\dfrac{dS}{dt}$  represent the growth rate of the populations.

I need to provide interpretation on $aCS$ and $eCS$, $b$ and $p$. Could I say that the growth rate of the chicken species is dependant on the number of snake; the growth rate of snake is dependant on chicken; $a$ and $e$ is the interaction strength of the two species? As such how do I interpret $b$ and $\rho$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 1):

This is a 2 compartimental system, the way you interpret is: you have the chicken $C$, the snakes $S$ and the interaction $CS$; the constant $b$ tells you how much the chicken reproduce, as well as $e$ tells you for the snakes, since this species depends on the preying; the other constants tells you how much the species are dying.

Think about this: if $b,e,a,\rho < 0$, what happens then?

Comment: Do you mind to elaborate more? I am confused.

Comment: I can give you a hint: rewrite the expressions changing the signs, what does this new expression means?